# ReactJS: Trying to render new screen after login with form, taking data from Express JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

I haven't figured out how to update the page in my SPA application after a successful login in a form. I manage to send the data to the API from the form using a proxy just fine, but the API then replies with a JSON of the user_ID and I need the React frontend to check that the ID is there and then render the next screen past the login screen, but I don't know how to unrender the login screen and render the next one.

ReactJS Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../public/styles/App.css'
import Header from "./header.js"

var recID = []

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user: []
        }

        this.checkLogin = this.checkLogin.bind(this)
    }

    checkLogin() {
        fetch('/api/user')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user_id => this.setState({user: user_id}))
    recID = recID.concat(this.state.user)
    console.log(recID)
    console.log(recID.length)
    if (recID.length == 6) {
        this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})
    }
    }

    loginScreen() {
        return(   
            <div style={{border:"none"}}>
                <div style={{background:"white"}}>
                <br></br>
                    <center><Header /></center>
                <br></br>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <div style={{background:"white"}}>
                <center><form action='/api/login' method="POST" onSubmit={this.checkLogin()}>
                    <br></br>
                    Username: <br></br>
                    <input type = "text" name= "username"></input>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    Password: <br></br>
                    <input type = "text" name = "password"></input>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Log-in"></input>
                    <br></br>
                </form></center>
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    success() {
        return (
            <div>
              <p>TEST</p>
              {this.state.user && this.state.user.map(us => <div key={us.user_id}>{us.user_id} </div>)}
            </div>
          )
    }

    render() {
            if (this.state.isLoggedIn == true) {
                return (
                    this.success()
                )
            }
            else {
                return (
                    this.loginScreen()
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Express NodeJS relevant code:

...

```
app.post("/api/login", async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const id = await users.login(req.body.username, req.body.password)
    console.log(id)
    currentID = currentID.concat(id)
})

app.get("/api/user", async(req, res) => {
    res.json(currentID)
    currentID = []
})
```

Instead of a whole page, I have a test case instead. Any advice on how to change renders after an event is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to check for `isLoggedIn` instead of `loggedIn` unless its a typo for example code in render method `this.state.loggedIn == true`

Comment: Yeah, was just a typo, thanks for pointing it out! Problem still persists though.

Comment: Are you getting confirmation that `state.isLoggedIn` is turning to `true`?

Comment: I've just put a console.log in after the state change, it doesn't even seem to get to the checkLogin() function. I'm guessing there's some kind of error with getting it to do it after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues here.

Remove `action='/api/login' method="POST"` from `<form>`

Modify your `onSubmit={this.checkLogin}` to function reference instead of calling it.

Add `e.preventDefault()` in `checkLogin(e)` and that should resolve your issue.

Modify your fetch to handle POST

example from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Lastly you need to modify your inputs to React controlled elements follow example here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html 
From which you would consume values and pass it to fetch as payload.

What's happening is you are submitting form and form triggers POST to action URL which is causing browser reload.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../public/styles/App.css'
import Header from "./header.js"

var recID = []

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user: []
        }

        this.checkLogin = this.checkLogin.bind(this)
    }

    checkLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
        fetch('/api/user')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user_id => this.setState({user: user_id}))
    recID = recID.concat(this.state.user)
    console.log(recID)
    console.log(recID.length)
    if (recID.length == 6) {
        this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})
    }
    }

    loginScreen() {
        return(   
            <div style={{border:"none"}}>
                <div style={{background:"white"}}>
                <br></br>
                    <center><Header /></center>
                <br></br>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <div style={{background:"white"}}>
                <center><form onSubmit={this.checkLogin}>
                    <br></br>
                    Username: <br></br>
                    <input type = "text" name= "username"></input>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    Password: <br></br>
                    <input type = "text" name = "password"></input>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Log-in"></input>
                    <br></br>
                </form></center>
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    success() {
        return (
            <div>
              <p>TEST</p>
              {this.state.user && this.state.user.map(us => <div key={us.user_id}>{us.user_id} </div>)}
            </div>
          )
    }

    render() {
            if (this.state.isLoggedIn == true) {
                return (
                    this.success()
                )
            }
            else {
                return (
                    this.loginScreen()
                )
            }
    }
}
```

```html
Remove action='/api/login' method="POST" from <form>

Add e.preventDefault() in CheckLogin and that should resolve your issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form, just remove the action and method. just call

```
 onSubmit={ev => this.checkLogin(ev)}
```

Then, be careful with this part of your code

```
fetch('/api/user')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user_id => this.setState({user: user_id}))
    recID = recID.concat(this.state.user)
```

this.setState() is asynchronous. you should do it this way:

```
fetch('/api/user')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user_id => this.setState(
{user: user_id},
() =>  recID = recID.concat(this.state.user)))
```

Also, make an ev.preventDefault() inside the checkLogin function.